# Find people to work on an android project

Tags: android, open-source

I'm started to get my feet wet with the android framework, and wanted to work on a game but was looking for a partner to work with. I was wondering if there are sites online where people can talk about a project and possibly collaborate and start a new project.

I realize this might be a stupid question, and not appropriate for this board. If so, I apologize.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a job-board

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the irc channel #android-dev on freenode.net, or join any of the many Android dev groups on LinkedIn, Facebook, Xing.